# Java compilation through command prompt issue

Tags: java, compiler-errors, prompt

[image: My bad attempt that is the same as what I did with checker]I tried to compile my class file "checker.class" into "checker.java" through the use of the javac command, planning to run it with the java command, but javac either gave me the issue of "file not found" OR "invalid flag" (when I tried to put checker in quotations.)
I would also like to understand the issue itself better and not just know the solution. Thanks.

What I attempted:

C:\Users\jaede\Desktop\everything>javac checker.class

C:\Users\jaede\Desktop\everything>javac "checker.class"

Results with error messages:

1. error: file not found: Checker.java
     Usage: javac  
     use --help for a list of possible options

   2. error: invalid flag: Checker.class                                                                                                               Usage: javac

   use --help for a list of possible options

planned to do:

C:\Users\jaede\Desktop\everything>java checker.java

*Sidenote: I probably do not have an environment variable issue, since I could run this with another .java files with the java command [image: My prebuilt fibonacci number generator.]

Comment: `javac` takes source files. You have the commands exactly backwards. `javac Checker.java` then `java Checker` (it knows to use `Checker.class`).

Comment: I found that I am able to run some .java files with the java, I don't understand how that works if It must be .class.

Comment: Java 9 added jshell. But you're just using `java`. What **version** of Java? And **how** do you run some `.java` files with the java? What command? We cannot see your screen. Only what you have added to your question. But, in **general**, javac compiles java source files into java class files. `javac` will not compile a compiled class file. It never has.

Comment: I don't think I have this issue anymore, and I would just like to clarify something: how do you run .class files made with the javac command? I think that my question is still relevent, so I will keep it as it is.

Comment: I also added the command line prompts I used when I didn't know these things you commenters mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got .class and .java mixed up. The comments to the original post have the full rundown.